# What's this jQuery code snippet doing?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password)
```

`$([])` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

> jQuery( elementArray )
>
> elementArrayAn array containing a set
>   of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery
>   object.

In this case, the selected array is initially empty.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's creating an array and adding name, email, and password into it.

in javascript `[]` is just an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that creates a jQuery Object with nothing selected inside it. Generally you pass a selector to jQuery to select page elements, and then preform actions on them.

```
$('.myElements');
```

Instead, this just creates a jQuery Object that has nothing selected, which you can then use jQuery functions to add stuff to it.

```
$([]);
```

It then uses the add function to populate the object with certain selectors.

See the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function.